# How to troubleshoot errors in workflow status?

Tags: workflow

I'm experiencing an error for the status of my workflow:

[image]

And here's the description:

[image]

I researched the issue, and Microsoft website gave this:

[image]

I have many workflows and it's going to take a long time to find out the cause of the error by looking at each workflow actions one by one. Is there a faster way to troubleshoot this error to find the root cause? Maybe log files or something like that if sharepoint designer has that?

Comment: on the same page where you see the workflow history you will find internal status, it will have a blue colored (i) or the information symbol click on that, it will display the root exception of error. you may get better hint from that

Comment: Hi, thanks for your comment! Where can I find the workflow history? @AkshayRandive

Comment: select the item for which WF errored, from ribbon select Worflow, you will see list of execution history click on Error Occurred link it will take you to the page where you can see this

Comment: I'm not sure which item did the WF error occurred for though. Sorry to trouble you but is it alright if you provide some pictorial solutions?

Answer (score 1):

On the same page where you see the workflow history you will find internal status, it will have a blue colored (i) or the information symbol click on that, it will display the root exception of error. you may get better hint from that.

[image]

[image]

Comment: I see. My 2nd image already shows the (general) cause of error for that but I'm trying to figure out the specific reason.

Comment: on second page click on the link under status column it will redirect you to second screenshot where you see the exact exception

Comment: I don't have that blue (i) button. I'm using SP2013. Could it be due to a difference in version?

Comment: After clicking on **workflows** (according to your first image), it brings me to this page: https://ibb.co/mxjhp6, where there isn't any blue (i) button. @Akshay Randive

Comment: right now you can click on "Error Occurred"  link under Internal Status column

Comment: It brings me to the 2nd image i posted in my question